# Printing long comments in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I have a Word document with many long comments. If I try to print it normally the comments are cut off.

I can print just the comments themselves following [these instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286169) but I need to be able to print the document with the comments in the proper context.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you make your margins wide (either in the print preview window or in layout when editing the document) the comments may be able to all fit.